# Designators in CRAM framework

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just finished reading CRAM core and KnowRob, and I have an overview of the system at this moment.

I have read the following information:

- KnowRob wiki (http://www.ros.org/wiki/knowrob)
- KnowRob PhD dissertation
- Several articles about CRAM, some of them from  TUM webpage (http://ias.cs.tum.edu/research/cram)
- CRAM information in ROS.org (http://www.ros.org/wiki/cram_core)

However, I still do not understand "designators" in CRAM. How they work? Do you know where I can find more information about them? "Designators" are the module most interesting for me. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44105/designators-in-cram-framework/) by [dgerod](https://answers.ros.org/users/1843/dgerod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgerod](https://answers.ros.org/users/1843/dgerod/) on 2012-09-19**:
@makokal - Thanks for your answer but the link is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for you interest in that package. You just made me create some documentation on the [wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/cram_designators). It should give you a high-level overview of what designators are and how their interface looks like. For examples on how to use them, have a look at the source code of the package `cram_plan_library` in the stack [`cram_highlevel`](https://github.com/moesenle/cram_highlevel.git). Packages that implement specialized location resolution mechanisms in that stack are:

- location_costmap: provides basic functionality to construct costmaps for sampling location designator solutions.
- semantic_map_costmap: uses Knowrob's semantic map to generate costmaps for generating poses `on`, `in` etc. objects in the semantic map, e.g. on the counter top.
- occupancy_grid_costmap: provides a simple implementation for poses to see and to reach specific poses by using the 2d map provided by navigation for inferring locations the robot can navigate to.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgerod](https://answers.ros.org/users/1843/dgerod/) on 2012-09-25**:
Thanks a lot for your answer. I did not answer before because I was on holidays.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps this paper would give you what you need
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=05650989

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgerod](https://answers.ros.org/users/1843/dgerod/) on 2012-10-10**:
The link is working now, thanks.